# React - How to pass data from a composed child component to a composed parent component?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

In order to pass data from a child component to a parent component in React, the parent passes an update function down to the child, and then the child can call this to pass data up.

*Question: *However, I wonder if it's possible to do the same thing when using composition?

For example, I would like to create a `SwitchGroup` component that can be wrapped around a number of `Switch` components using composition. The idea of the `SwitchGroup` component is that it would keep track of state of any `Switches` in its group and when there is only one `Switch` enabled, it would disable the remaining one so that it is not possible to switch off all the switches in the group.

```
<SwitchGroup>
    <Switch onChangeHandler={updateParent} />
    <Switch onChangeHandler={updateParent} />
    <Switch onChangeHandler={updateParent} />
</SwitchGroup>
```

Of course, I could keep track of all of this in a component that contained the `SwitchGroup` and the `Switches`, but I would like "componentize" this behaviour so that it is reusable in lots of locations.

I have used a pattern where the components aren't composed, but want to use composition.

Comment: Can SwitchGroup only contains Switch components ?

Comment: Yes @FlorentM. It can only contain Switch components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `SwitchGroup` can only contains `Switch` components as children, i would suggest another approach consisting of passing the options of the switches as prop into the `SwitchGroup`

Something like this :

```
interface ISwitchProps {
 label: string;
 isChecked: boolean;
 onChange(value: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>): void; 
 // etc...
}

interface ISwitchGroupProps {
 // onChange and isChecked will be passed to the Switches from the SwitchGroup. 
 // If you want to be able to set a default value for `isChecked` you can
 // remove it  from the Omit and make it optionnal
 switches: Omit<ISwitchProps, 'onChange', 'isChecked'>[];
 // Just an example, imagine a method returning the value of all the 
 // switches everytime on is checked / unchecked as a Record with 
 // the label as a key
 onSwitchChanges(values: Record<string, boolean>): void
}
```

Inside the `SwitchGroup` we can have something like this :

```
// Store all the values of the switches by label
const [checkValues, setCheckValues] = useState<Record<string, boolean>>();

// Set the checkValues at init (false is set by default, 
// but you can change that with another option in ISwitchProps)
useEffect(() => {
 setCheckValues(switches.reduce((acc, current) => ({
   ...acc,
   [current.label]: false
 }), {});
},[])

// Every time checkValues is updated, we call the parent method
useEffect(() => onSwitchChanges(checkValues), [checkValues]);

return (
 <div className="switch-group">
   {switches.map((switch) => (
     <Switch 
       label={switch.label} 
       isChecked={checkValues[switch.label]}
       onChange={(value) => setCheckValues({
         ...checkValues, 
         [switch.label]: value
       })}
      />
   ))}
 </div>
)
```

Then we call the `SwitchGroup` like this :

```
<SwitchGroup 
  switches={[{label: 'Switch 1'}, {label: 'Switch 2'}]
  onSwitchChanges={// do something} 
/>
```

It is a quick and very imperfect example, but i hope you get the idea :)

Comment: @FlorentM Yes, this makes much more sense to me. Thanks for taking the time to answer :)